# order by within group concat

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, group-concat

The order by is not working in the second query.
I need to order by first DNAID then DNBID

First Query its ordered as:
111221

Second Query its ordered as:
112112

for more info and details about what im trying to accomplish
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082880/database-query-group-union-find-latest

```
mysql> select * from metarun;
+----+------------+-------+-------+--------------+----------+
| ID | RunGroupID | DNAID | DNBID | CONFIGTYPEID | DateTime |
+----+------------+-------+-------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |     1 |     1 |            2 | NULL     |
|  2 |          1 |     1 |     2 |            2 | NULL     |
|  3 |          1 |     2 |     1 |            2 | NULL     |
|  4 |          2 |     1 |     1 |            4 | NULL     |
|  5 |          2 |     3 |     2 |            4 | NULL     |
|  6 |          3 |     3 |     2 |            1 | NULL     |
|  7 |          3 |     1 |     2 |            1 | NULL     |
|  8 |          3 |     3 |     1 |            1 | NULL     |
|  9 |          4 |     1 |     1 |            3 | NULL     |
| 10 |          4 |     2 |     1 |            3 | NULL     |
| 11 |          4 |     1 |     2 |            3 | NULL     |
| 12 |          5 |     1 |     1 |            2 | NULL     |
| 13 |          5 |     2 |     1 |            2 | NULL     |
| 14 |          5 |     1 |     2 |            2 | NULL     |
| 15 |          6 |     3 |     2 |            4 | NULL     |
| 16 |          6 |     1 |     1 |            4 | NULL     |
+----+------------+-------+-------+--------------+----------+



mysql> SELECT RunGroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(DNAID, DNBID SEPARATOR ''), ConfigTypeID, DateTime
    -> FROM metarun
    -> GROUP BY RunGroupID
    -> ORDER BY RunGroupID, DNAID ASC, DNBID ASC;
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
| RunGroupID | GROUP_CONCAT(DNAID, DNBID SEPARATOR '') | ConfigTypeID | DateTime |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
|          1 | 111221                                  |            2 | NULL     |
|          2 | 1132                                    |            4 | NULL     |
|          3 | 123132                                  |            1 | NULL     |
|          4 | 111221                                  |            3 | NULL     |
|          5 | 111221                                  |            2 | NULL     |
|          6 | 1132                                    |            4 | NULL     |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT RunGroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(DNAID, DNBID SEPARATOR ''), ConfigTypeID, DateTime
    -> FROM metarun
    -> WHERE configtypeid=2
    -> GROUP BY RunGroupID
    -> ORDER BY RunGroupID;
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
| RunGroupID | GROUP_CONCAT(DNAID, DNBID SEPARATOR '') | ConfigTypeID | DateTime |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
|          1 | 111221                                  |            2 | NULL     |
|          5 | 112112                                  |            2 | NULL     |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can specify an `ORDER BY` clause in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT RunGroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(DNAID, DNBID ORDER BY DNAID, DNBID SEPARATOR '')
```